# How to update master table with value 0 if there are no records in the detail table

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I have 2 tables in Firebird 3 db - master table "Docs" for output documents and detail table "Recs" for sold goods.

- Columns of `Docs`: doc_id, summa
- Columns of `Recs`: id, doc_id, goods, price, qnt

When customer cancels sale this record remains in detail table, didn't remove it and after update trigger updates total `summa` of master table.

Trigger works well before last record remains in output table. But if customer cancels last sale and detail dataset becomes empty trigger didn't work correctly and shows `summa` of last record instead of 0.

How correct this trigger?

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER RECS_AU FOR Recs
 ACTIVE AFTER UPDATE POSITION 0
 AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE Price DECIMAL(12, 4);
  DECLARE VARIABLE Doc_id INTEGER;
  DECLARE VARIABLE OLD_Price DECIMAL(12, 4);
  BEGIN
   select 
    r.Doc_id,
    coalesce(sum(r.Price*r.Qnt),0)
   from Recs r, Docs d
   where r.Doc_id=new.Doc_id and r.Doc_id=d.Doc_id and r.status<>'deleted'
   group by r.Doc_id
   into :Doc_id, :Summa;
    
     update Docs set
      Docs.Summa=:Summa:
     where Doc_id=:Doc_id;
```

I know that problem is in writing correct SQL, not in trigger. After dataset becomes empty it returns empty record set. Why doesn't work coalesce in case of empty dataset and doesn't show `summa` as 0?

```
SELECT 
    doc_id,
    coalesce(SUM(cast((r.price*r.qnt) as decimal(18,4))),0) as summa
FROM 
    recs r
WHERE 
    doc_id= :doc_id AND status <> 'deleted'
GROUP BY
    doc_id
```

Comment: If there are no applicable `Recs` remaining, then the select statement in the Trigger returns no records, not 1 record with a zero value. You need to stop using equijoins. Use left-joins intead.

Comment: Actually the problem is in doing SELECT at all instead of using NEW and OLD contexts. The trigger's logic is wrong. It must adjust "Summa" value using data from the current record only instead of calculating of the sum of all records.

Comment: @FreddieBell If I exclude 'group by' it doesn't matter which join I will use- inner join or left join, both works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Freddie Bell mentions in the comments, the problem is that you're using an implicit inner join. Meaning that when there are no rows in `RECS` for a row in `DOCS`, then there will be no row due to the presence of the `GROUP BY`.

You either need to use an explicit `LEFT JOIN` as suggested by Freddie, only select from `RECS` without joining `DOCS` (and leave out the `GROUP BY`), or even simpler, just perform an update with a correlated sub-select without first executing a select separately:

```sql
update DOCS d set d.Summa = (
  select coalesce(sum(r.Price*r.Qnt), 0)
  from RECS r
  where r.DOC_ID = d.DOC_ID and r.STATUS <> 'deleted'
)
where d.DOC_ID = :NEW.DOC_ID
```

This will work, even if there are no rows in `RECS`, because absent a `GROUP BY`, this will produce a row when there are no matching rows in `RECS`.

Comment: Such update will encounter visibility problem on concurrency. In most cases it should end up in update conflict error, but on forums I saw that some developers managed to get wrong sums silently. (I have no idea how, stupidity is too inclusive.)

Comment: @user13964273 There will only be concurrency issues if multiple transactions modify the DOCS or RECS for the same DOC_ID concurrently, and if that is the case, they already have that problem with the existing trigger.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If I exclude 'group by' it doesn't matter which join I will use- inner join or left join, both works correctly.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Excuse me but I was wrong- there are 4 sums in my SQL, not 1. I oversimplified my SQL.  How my I use sub-select in this case?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel After I exclude 'doc_id' and 'group by', my initial code works fine. It works even without  left join. I exclude group by and it works. You set me on the wright path. Thank you.

Comment: @basti Yes, without a `GROUP BY` it will indeed work, because then the aggregate function will always produce a row, however, from a performance perspective, ask yourself: why would you execute two statements when one will do.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right but I don't know if it's possible modify  you code for updating 4 summa, not only 1? May you show how?

Comment: @basti You mean you have four columns to update or four rows? If four rows, it should already work, if four columns, then use [`MERGE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-merge) instead. In any case, you're moving the goalposts of your question, and in that case you should ask a new question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 4 columns. Thank you.

Comment: @basti _It works even without left join_ Why do you have Docs table in the select statement to begin with? This answer clearly says it's not needed at all and unless you haven't shown some important details - it's completely useless to have it in the query.

Comment: @BrakNicku You are right. I already recreate trigger without docs and it works fine. Thank you.